# Bluetooth InputStrem reading bytes in two parts

Tags: android, bluetooth, inputstream, android-bluetooth

I'm using bluetooth serial connection to communicate between android app and micro controller. I'm able to communicate between App and MC. But the message I'm sending from MC splits in to two parts. For Example if I send `$F05,A,B,C,0#` over bluetooth it splits my message into two parts and reads as follows. The first part is `$` and rest is `F05,A,B,C,0#`. You can see my log cat output as follows.

```
12-24 10:40:19.926 17999-18183/? V/PRAVEEN: $
12-24 10:40:20.027 17999-18183/? V/PRAVEEN: F15,A,0,0,0#
```

I send this message in whole nut android splits into two parts. My code is

```
        public void run() {
        try{
            int bytes;
            while (true){
                try{
                    avilableBytes=inputStream.available();
                    byte[] buffer=new byte[avilableBytes];
                    if (avilableBytes>0){
                        bytes=inputStream.read(buffer);
                        final String readMessage=new String(buffer);
                        Log.v("PRAVEEN",readMessage);
                        if (bytes>=3){
                            bt_handler.obtainMessage(handlerState,bytes,-1,readMessage).sendToTarget();
                        }
                        else {
                            SystemClock.sleep(100);
                        }
                    }
                }catch (IOException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Please assist me in getting the actual string I'm sending. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, it happens, several times, sometimes you will get data like `$F05`,`,A,B,C,0#`.

Comment: @NigamPatro is there a workaround or hack like something to achieve that?

Comment: Till now I am searching for that, but we can do something like, we can append some special character to distinguish the message blocks.

Comment: I have done stuff like this in the past. I think you need to switch a line to append instead of start from scratch. I'll pull up my code in the morning.

Comment: @NickFelker yeah thanks. please do post your code.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're using rfcomm, here's how you could do it. In my example I send two payloads: the first is the size of the message, the second is the message itself.

```
while (true) {
            Log.d(TAG, "listening to InputStream");
            try {
                // Read from the InputStream
                int messageSizeBufferSize = mmInStream.readInt();
                Log.d(TAG, messageSizeBufferSize+"<mSBS");
                Log.d(TAG, "Run");

                if(messageSizeBufferSize == 0)
                    continue;
                Log.d(TAG, "Message of size "+messageSizeBufferSize);
                bytes = 0;
                buffer = new byte[messageSizeBufferSize];
                while(bytes < messageSizeBufferSize) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Reading bits "+bytes+" for mmInStream");
                    bytes += mmInStream.read(buffer,bytes,messageSizeBufferSize - bytes);
                }
                Log.d(TAG, "Read RFCOMM message completely");
                String message = new String(buffer);
                Log.d(TAG, "Read "+message);
            } catch (IOException e) {

                break;
            }
        }
```